# Последовательный вывод данных в ячейки таблицы (массив или объект)

Tags: jquery

Необходимо при помощи Jquery последовательно, с задержкой в 1 секунду, выводить данные в ячейки  таблицы. Количество строк  динамично. Заголовок и подвал таблицы при этом остаются неизменными.

```js
var jtable = [{
    strkod: 353,
    strloc: "склад 1",
    strtab: 25468,
    strkat1: 0,
    strkat2: 1,
    strkat3: 1,
    strkat4: 0,
    strprim: ""
  },
  {
    strkod: 682,
    strloc: "склад 2",
    strtab: 98562,
    strkat1: 1,
    strkat2: 0,
    strkat3: 1,
    strkat4: 1,
    strprim: ""
  }
];
    ViewTable (jtable); //передача внутри Ajax
function ViewTable (Vtbl){
    ; //дальше запутался
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Код</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Локация</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Номер</th>
      <th colspan="4">Категория</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Примечание</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <th colspan="4">Кнопка "НАЗАД"</th>
    <th colspan="4">Кнопка "Отправить"</th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Ссылка на https://jsfiddle.net/Mister_X_2k/hzmkc2f5

PS: перебрал кучу скриптов, запутался, но решения так и не смог написать. Чтобы не вводить в заблуждение профи свои ошибочные изыскания не привожу.

)))Извините, если задачу описал не в полном объеме.
Дополнение: массив/объект "jtable" получаю из Ajax-запроса в виде json. Здесь привожу как пример парочки строк вывода. Каждая строка вывода содержит одинаковые идентификаторы, различны только их значения.
Для точного описания задачи:

1. первая строка:

   - "strkod",
   - задержка 1 секунда выводится "strloc",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strloc",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strtab",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat1",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat2",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat3",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat4",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strprim";
2. вторая строка:

   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkod",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strloc",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strtab",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat1",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat2",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat3",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strkat4",
   - задержка 1 секунда - "strprim";

и т.д. весь массив данных.

Comment: Какие строки выводить нужно ?

Comment: "Чтобы не вводить в заблуждение профи свои ошибочные изыскания не привожу." - - не волнуйтесь за "профи". Мы что, должны сами сочинить пример с данными и их распределением по строкам и столбцам таблицы? Это - вряд ли. -1

Comment: Igor, приношу свои извинения за введение Вас в заблуждение...
вариант данных для вывода добавил с "дополнением"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var jtable = [{
    strkod: 353,
    strloc: "склад 1",
    strtab: 25468,
    strkat1: 0,
    strkat2: 1,
    strkat3: 1,
    strkat4: 0,
    strprim: ""
  },
  {
    strkod: 682,
    strloc: "склад 2",
    strtab: 98562,
    strkat1: 1,
    strkat2: 0,
    strkat3: 1,
    strkat4: 1,
    strprim: ""
  },
  {
    strkod: 777,
    strloc: "склад 3",
    strtab: 98562,
    strkat1: 12,
    strkat2: 0,
    strkat3: 12,
    strkat4: 12,
    strprim: "222"
  }
];
ViewTable (jtable); //передача внутри Ajax
function ViewTable (data, iRow, iCell) {
  if (typeof iRow == "undefined")
    iRow = 0;
  if (typeof iCell == "undefined")
    iCell = 0;

  if (iRow >= data.length)
    return;
    
  var row = $("table tbody tr").last();
  if (!row.length) {
    row = $("<tr/>");
    $("table tbody").append(row);
  }

  var keys = Object.keys(data[iRow]);
  if (iCell >= keys.length) {
    iRow++;
    iCell = 0;
    if (iRow >= data.length)
      return;
    row = $("<tr/>");
    $("table tbody").append(row);
  }

  var keys = Object.keys(data[iRow]);
  var cell = $("<td/>");
  cell.text(data[iRow][keys[iCell]]);
  row.append(cell);
    
  setTimeout(ViewTable, 1000, data, iRow, iCell + 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Код</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Локация</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Номер</th>
      <th colspan="4">Категория</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Примечание</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <th colspan="4">Кнопка "НАЗАД"</th>
    <th colspan="4">Кнопка "Отправить"</th>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Igor, спасибо за напутствие. Можно ли докрутить Ваш код так чтобы вывод значения в следующую ячейку производился после секундной задержки, а не вся строка сразу?

Comment: @WarDoctor Можно. Изменил.

Comment: огромнейшее спасибо, что помогли с поиском решения. Не поверите, за две недели мозги уже совсем отказались воспринимать последовательность выполнения задачи...

Comment: @WarDoctor Почему же не поверю? Еще как поверю ).

Comment: еще вопрос: обязательно ли в вызове функции давать начальный индекс?
" ViewTable (jtable, 0); //передача внутри Ajax " или можно обойтись без стартового?

Comment: @WarDoctor Можно. Изменил.

Comment: еще раз огромное СПАСИБО. Это как раз "то что доктор прописал")))